# how to get the clear event of search box in jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Define a search box 
If the  input box have some text  , the input box will display a clear button,  how to get click  event of  Clear button?

```
<label for="search-mini">Search Input:</label>
<input type="search" name="search-mini" id="search-mini" value="" data-mini="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Input with `type=search` are enhanced with clear `<a>` anchor button which has class `ui-input-clear`. You can attach events to that button as follows.

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/75VZf/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-input-clear', function () {
  alert('text cleared');
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm.
i wonder why simply $('.ui-input-clear').click(function(){ // some code});  doesnt work.

Comment: @rDroid because it's dynamically created therefore you need to delegate the event. Your code above can be wrapped in `pagecreate` event, but you should specify page to avoid multiplied listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `.click()` listener that's included with jQuery. Example:

```
$('#clear-button').click(function(){
    $('#search-box').val('');
    // OR WHATEVER OTHER CODE YOU WANT TO RUN WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED
});
```

Assuming that the "id" attribute of your button is "clear-button".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Improving a little bit on Omar's answer, you can get more specific with the selector so that the event doesn't listen to every single element with the `ui-input-clear` class.

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/75VZf/6/)

HTML:

```
<div id="search-container">
    <label for="search-mini">Search Input:</label>
    <input type="search" name="search-mini" id="search-mini" value="" data-mini="true" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#search-container .ui-input-clear', function () {
  alert('text cleared');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    $('#clear').click(function(){
        $('#search').val('');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/KPZMQ/